# Is puppeteer supplying real time data

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I'm trying to web scrape a live scores every score change. Can puppeteer do this? If it can what should I add in this code so it returns live data.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('site to go');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[name="username"]');
  await page.type('input[name="username"]', 'username');
  await page.type('input[name="password"]', 'password');
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
  let score = await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `exposeFunction` to register a callback function:

```js
await page.exposeFunction('newScore', s => console.log(s));
```

Then you can call that function on the `DOMSubtreeModified` event:

```js
page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('scores')
  .addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', () => newScore(element.innerHTML)));
```

Comment: how about every 10 seconds it returns data

Comment: @Newboy11 you could solve that on your side using `setInterval` and calling evaluate inside of it.